# Add a parameter to a google maps geocoder function

Tags: jquery, google-maps, parameters

I want to create a geocoder function, which write the result to it's parameter.

```
  function geoCode(latlng,div) {
    gc.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: result[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
      $(div).html(result[0].formatted_address);
    }            
  });
```

How can I add the div parameter to the geocoder function?

Like this:

```
gc.geocode({'latLng': latlng, writeHere: div}, function (result, status) {
...
$(writeHere).html(result[0].formatted_address);
}
```

But it's doesn't working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function geoCode(latlng, div) {
    var $div = jq(div);
    gc.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: result[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
            $div.html(result[0].formatted_address);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No... I added a parameter to the geoCode function. I want to write the result to this 'div', but the 'gc.geocode' sub-function generate this result, and I can't add this 'div' parameter to this function.

Comment: The `div` variable should be accessible from that scope. You can try to add `var div = div;` just before you call `.geocode` but I'm not sure that this might be the problem. Btw, you are missing a closing bracket at the end.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I want give the 'div' to the call.

Comment: @kree: I've updated my answer, try that and see how it turns out.

Comment: My fault... I use noConflict to the $ character. The jq means $... I forget it

Comment: @Marcus: In your answer the variable would need to be a global variable. It isn't working for me.

Comment: @kree: No it shouldn't have to be a global var, but you can try but I'm pretty certain it will not matter. Something else is wrong here...